# Android Studio, как сделать так чтобы 2 слоя занимали по 50% экрана?

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

Изучаю android studio, встретился с такой проблемой, у меня есть экран на котором расположено 2 слоя LinearLayout, я хочу сделать так чтобы эти 2 слоя делили между собой пространство экрана 50 на 50, но не могу понять как это делается. Может быть кто-то может мне в этом подсказать? В интернете увы толком не смог найти никакой информации, пытался прописывать что-то в самом activity_main.xml тоже безуспешно..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать ConstraintLayout. Это улучшеный RelativeLayout, он функционален и быстр.

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4"
```

1. Оберните ваши контейнеры в <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
2. Откройте вкладку Design или Split вашей верстки.
3. Выделите контейнеры которые вы хотите скомпоновать.
4. Поэкспериментируйте с кнопка Align и Pack. Они позволяют групировать элементы различными образами.
5. Так же испытайте Guideline https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline
6. Как сказал @pavlofff для оптимизации не рекомендуется использовать вложенные контейнеры.

Отличный пример:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639504/android-studio-layout-editor-constraintlayout-pack-vs-chain

Пример xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="204dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/second"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="204dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/first">

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ваш ответ, я сделал всё как вы описали, сработало, но появилась другая проблема, 2 слоя делят между собой пространство 50/50 но отображаются совершенно по разному на разных экранах, на маленьком экране всё отлично, а на большом  между ними появляется пустое пространство, не подскажите чем с этим можно справиться?

Comment: Это скорее всего связано с тем что задана фиксированная ширина(android:layout_width="204dp"). Попробуйте в примере Vlad Orlinskas изменить эти значения в обоих LinearLayout и поставьте android:layout_width="0dp".

Comment: ConstraintLayout - разрабатывался специально как одноуровневый контейнер. Задача была увеличить скорость отрисовки за счет избавления от вложенных контейнеров, на просчет которых тратились существенные ресурсы. Пихать туда другие контейнеры, как LinearLayout - насмешка над разработчиками этого контейнера, тем более что его собственные инструменты позволяют разделить экран пополам гораздо проще и эффективнее, не говоря уже о том, что разрекламированное вами же "функционален и быстр"  бездарно теряется при вашем подходе с вложенными контейнерами. Крайне дилетанский пример решения.

Comment: @pavlofff полностью с вами согласен, я лишь хотел направить человека на изучение нового. Вполне вероятно знакомство с этим контейнером и его возможностями опустило бы вопрос вовсе. Спасибо, вы побудили меня дописать иное решение, остальную критику можно выразить голосами за ответ.

Comment: @VladOrlinskas - Здравствуйте, ещё раз благодарю за ваш ответ, разобрался как всё работает, всё сделал)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте вес (атрибут `android:weight`). Примерно так:

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weight="1" />

     <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weight="1" />

  </LinearLayout>
```